# How to generate random non-overlapping platforms in SFML?

Tags: c++, random, sfml

I just started learning C++ and SFML, and I'm writing game like doodle jump.
I have three different platforms. My platforms are set randomly but... overlapped. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's part of my code:

```
int main()
{

srand(time(NULL));

RenderWindow app(VideoMode(600, 600), "Doodle Game!");
app.setFramerateLimit(60);

Texture t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
t1.loadFromFile("4.png");
t2.loadFromFile("platform.png");
t3.loadFromFile("cartoon.png");
t4.loadFromFile("rock.png");
t5.loadFromFile("wood.png");


Sprite sBackground(t1), sPlat(t2), sPlat1(t4), sPlat2(t5), sPers(t3);
sPers.setScale(0.3f, 0.3f);
sPlat.setScale(0.06f, 0.06f);
sPlat1.setScale(0.06f, 0.06f);
sPlat2.setScale(0.06f, 0.06f);

point plat[20];
point plat1[20];
point plat2[20];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
   plat[i].x=rand()%600;
   plat[i].y=rand()%600;
   plat1[i].x=rand()%600;
   plat1[i].y=rand()%600;
   plat2[i].x=rand()%600;
   plat2[i].y=rand()%600;
  }
```

Comment: And how that doesn't work for you?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I want my platforms not to overlap

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random also https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Many random numbers in C++ can be generated using [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), or, in a pinch, `rand()` though this facility is old and not recommended.

Comment: "I want my platforms not to overlap" Then perhaps you want to ask about generating random non-overlapping platforms, rather than about generating random numbers.

Comment: Ok, sorry, you're right.

Comment: The brute force approach is to check whether a new platform overlaps the existing ones, based on all platforms' coordinates. There's no magic button you can push, and have this result come out. You have to code this logic yourself. Something like this is fine, when self-teaching programming. But it's inefficient, and suboptimal. The logically correct approach is to record the areas of the screen, represented as a list of rectangles, that are empty. Pick a random location, within those rectangles, then update the list to reflect the updated empty screen area. Surprisingly complicated logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific amount of random numbers, where each is unique, then besides the [pseudo-random classes and functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), you could use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Simply loop and generate random numbers until the size of the set is the required amount of numbers you need.